# How to add another account to an SQS Queue

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

We have set up our terraform script to create an SQS for one account only.

There is demand add more accounts for the future.

I was wondering if anyone has a way of adding an account (quick fix) to this code without changing everything completely?

```
environment_override                = "enviorment_name"
enable_cross_account                = true
remote_aws_account                  = "*************"
encryption_key                      = ""
remote_account_roles                = [  "arn:aws:iam::*************:role/new_role ]
```

Where

> remote_aws_account
> and
> remote_account_roles

I need to add another one of each

can you just put it beside the other account number and role?

Thanks

Comment: That looks like it's a module rather than a resource? Could you please edit your question to include all the code necessary to form a [mcve]? Otherwise it's impossible for anyone to be able to say what needs to change to achieve what you want. You should also include in your question whether you are using AWS Organizations for the accounts you want access to and whether the SQS queue is always created in a specific account and whether that is the management AWS account.

Comment: To add up on the previous comment, the quickest fix would be to just add multiple invocations of the module with the secondary, tertiary accound ID, etc. If you are using a TF version > 0.13 you could potentially interpolate over a list of account_ids with for_each instead of invoking the module once per account.